HTTPS ok but ssh and ping fail on oracle cloud ubuntu instance
A short while ago, I had to reboot my Oracle cloud Ubuntu instance after I sent it a too large workload. After that, HTTP worked normally, but SSH and Ping both failed.
Here is what happen when I try Ping and SSH:
PS C:\> ping <ip--redacted>

Pinging <ip--redacted> with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for <ip--redacted>:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
Control-C
PS C:\> ssh ubuntu@<ip--redacted>
ssh: connect to host <ip--redacted> port 22: Connection timed out

Below is a screencap of my firewall configuration. I don't think it's the issue since it worked before I reboot the instance.

I still have full access to my second free instance on Oracle cloud (a CentOS-based linux).
What tracks should I explore before I just delete the instance and recreate one?

Log in on console and check if sshd is running and if any other firewall rules are present locally?

@vidarlo I actually can't login at all, Oracle does not feature any online console.
